# accessing ubuntu after downloading it

Tags: system-installation

I've downloaded ubuntu desktop 14.04, but where is it?  I didn't get asked anything during the download.  Do I have to log out of Windows before I can access it?  I turned the pc off and downloaded it again, but still can't find it

Ignore the tag as I don't understand them, I'm just adding one till its accepted

Comment: What you downloaded was not an installed Ubuntu OS, it was the Ubuntu installer. You need to burn the iso file that you downloaded to a DVD or put it on a USB flash drive using Universal USB Installer and then boot from it to start the Ubuntu installer. As for where the Ubuntu iso file that you downloaded is now, it's wherever you downloaded it to. Have you looked for it in your Downloads folder?

Comment: Two useful tutorials from www.ubuntu.com: 1) [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) 2) [How to create a bootable USB
stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Karel's comments are right. BTW to know where you downloaded the file to, you should have a look at your browser's download history.

Comment: Thanks, the files in downloads and I'm getting it sorted now

Answer (score 0):

You would most likely be looking for how to install ubuntu. There are countless guide scattered about the internet but here are some links to some easy guide to it
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Some things you will need beforehand, The operating system on a DVD or on a USB that is the big things you need to use these guides above. I hope I helped you with this, if you have anymore questions just ask all over the site.

(Also you dont just "Access" Ubuntu from your computer its a process that involves rebooting your computer, Windows 7 is an operating system, While ubuntu is also an operating system, Ubuntu however is free and does not cost large amounts of money like other operating systems. Also Do you just want to get ubuntu for anything in specific? As ubuntu is a very hard operating system to use if you have no other knowledge of it. Ask around on the site if you have any more questions about ubuntu) P.S Appropriate tags for this would be ubuntu installation or questions